# hide <a> text with css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to hide the "HOME" text and replace it with an image on my wordpress menu.
I am using the following css code right now:

```
li#menu-item-63 a {
background: url(/images/home.png) top center no-repeat;
width: 24px;
height:24px;
float: left;
text-ident: -9999px;
overflow: hidden;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

With the code above the image appears but the HOME text is still there. Thanks

Comment: I don't think hiding text with css like that is a good practice...why don't you just delete it from the skeleton or something??

Comment: how is deleting the text a better practice than hiding it? By using `text-indent`, you are allowing users with screen readers to still understand what links are about. Coupled with a `title` attribute, the link is perfectly viable *and* accessible

Comment: No need for overflow: hidden; and text-decoration since it will not appear.

Comment: Hidden Text will harm you on some search engine rankings. Removing form the source is better if you can.

Answer (score 9):

```
text-ident: -9999px;
```

should be

```
text-indent: -9999px;
```

Comment: For extra points, use -9999em instead of -9999px - that way, the indent will grow along with the text size, ensuring it's hidden no matter how big the text is.

Answer (score 1):

You could add

```
color: transparent;
```

to your style. Will hide the text.

Answer (score 0):

`text-indent`, not `text-ident`.

And `display: block`

Comment: display: inline-block; would work better most of the time, avoid the float hassle.